# Wanted to hide the submitted information from CloudPages Interactive Email page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpagesurl, interactive-email

We are collecting some personal information from SFMC surveys email templates. Upon submitting, the user is directed to a CloudPages Interactive Email page. Information submitted is encrypted and arrives in the browser URL

We can see, the answers submitted by users are visible in the thank you page URL. We want to hide such sensitive information.

Is there any way to hide the submitted information from the Cloud Pages URL Interactive Email page.

Comment: I don't see a way round this one. Form submission using GETs is supported by some email clients. None support POSTs. GETs transmit form data in the query string.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, the Interactive Email Form submission occurs via a GET which is what is supported by email clients and results in the submitted data being appended to the query string.  While you can't completely hide the data, there are some strategies to reduce the amount and meaning of the data included in the URL:

**Visible fields**

- Non-text input (select, radio, checkbox, button choice, image choice, rating)

  - The names (Data Attribute/Data Extension Field) and values (Option Field Value) can be obfuscated so that they do not relate back to the actual data being captured.
  - For example, instead of creating a DA named "FavoriteColor" and an Option Field Value like "Blue" (`&FavoriteColor=Blue` in the URL) you could use a DA named "A" and an option of "2" so that in the URL you then have `&A=2`.
- Text input

  - Since this is user generated, whatever the recipient types is what will be passed - unfortunately, that can't be changed. The Data Attribute, though, can be obfuscated as it can in non-text inputs.

**Hidden fields**

- When possible, pass a GUID which can be used to tie the submission back to the additional (sensitive) data that you need.